# IIS 8.5 Batch Update Folder Paths

Tags: migration, iis-8, web-farm, fileshare

We currently have a web farm of three servers and the application code is held on a fileshare on a separate device. We are running a project to migrate the applications to a separate storage device which will ultimately have a different root UNC file path.

We previously managed a similar operation on IIS 6 by simply modifying the metabase.xml file, however I don't believe this is a possibility in IIS 8.5

What is the best way to manage this migration considering that the web farm is running 200+ applications? Is there a convenient migration tool or configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more digging and running some tests on a Dev server, I found a fairly straightforward solution:

1. Run `cmd`
2. Navigate to the inetsrv folder: `cd %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv`
3. Run the following command to output a list of directories: `appcmd list vdir /config /xml > C:\VDirOutput.xml`
4. You can now edit the C:\VDirOutput.xml file manually using your favourite text editor to change the directory paths as required.
5. Import the new settings by running this command in `cmd`: `appcmd set vdir /in < C:\VDirOutput.xml`